# Expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

Tags: objective-c, class, cocos2d-iphone

I'm declaring:

CCSprite+DisableTouch.h file

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface CCSprite (DisableTouch) <CCTargetedTouchDelegate>  {

}

-(void)disableTouch;
-(void)enableTouch;

@end
```

And for the CCSprite+DisableTouch.m file

```
#import "CCSprite+DisableTouch.h"


@implementation CCSprite (DisableTouch)

-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)disableTouch
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:-1000 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

-(void)enableTouch
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
}

@end
```

why I get: `Expected identifier or '(' before '{' token` error?
How should I solve this one?

Comment: @Darren: first one: `@interface CCSprite (DisableTouch) <CCTargetedTouchDelegate>  {`, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is by adding the `{` & `}` characters to your category, as categories cannot have iVars.

If you need an iVar with your category, consider using associated objects:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

...

objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"iVar", @"value", OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);

...

id iVar = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @"iVar");
```

For more information on associated objects, look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html).

Answer (score 1):

As Richard said;  you can't add iVars in categories, and that is the source of the compiler warning/error.

However, there is something more subtle at play here.

If you are going to override behavior of CCSprite, you should be using a subclass, not a category.   By using a category, you will be changing the behavior of all CCSprite's in your application, which is quite unlikely to be the behavior you want (ask yourself this;  what would happen if your program had a UI element that used some out-of-the-box cocos2d -- or 3rd party -- UI that relied on the existing CCSprite touch behavior?)